# Liquibase : fixed value for a column in loaddata

Tags: liquibase

According to the liquibase documentation, the column tag has a value attribute. But apparently it is unauthorized when inside a loaddata ? This is at least the message (PAXParseException) I get when trying to load data as described below :

```
<loadData encoding="UTF-8"
              file="config/liquibase/translations/allTexts_fr.csv"
              separator=":="
              tableName="translation">
              <column name="lang" value="fr"/>
    </loadData>
```

How can I define such a loaddata ?

Same question goes with date columns, for instance a creation date that I would like to be initialized at "now", couldn't I specify this inside the loaddata somehow ?

Comment: Could you add the Stacktrace for the `PAXParseException`?

Comment: please did anybody find a solution for this ?